# How to loop a foreach on an object/array

Tags: php, for-loop, foreach

My `DB` returns an array of objects with arrays within.

## Var_dump

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[22]
      public 'customer_id' => string '10' (length=2)
      public 'cart' => string 'a:1:{s:32:"f9bb1d342b1c2a0bfe982ef405369ec0";a:9:{s:5:"rowid";s:32:"f9bb1d342b1c2a0bfe982ef405369ec0";s:2:"id";s:9:"101_30524";s:3:"qty";s:1:"1";s:5:"price";s:5:"104.5";s:4:"name";s:13:"Business Card";s:5:"image";s:18:"business-cards.gif";s:4:"ship";a:3:{s:6:"Ground";d:9.730000000000000426325641456060111522674560546875;s:11:"2nd Day Air";d:18.53999999999999914734871708787977695465087890625;s:9:"Overnight";d:26.269999999999999573674358543939888477325439453125;}s:7:"options";a:2:{s:17:"Print Description";s:16'... (length=761)
      public 'shipping_type' => string 'Ground' (length=6)
      public 'shipping_cost' => string '9.73' (length=4)
      public 'order_sub_total' => string '104.50' (length=6)
      public 'order_total' => string '114.23' (length=6)
      public 'id' => string '28' (length=2)
      public 'timestamp' => string '2012-10-12 20:10:30' (length=19)
  1 => 
    object(stdClass)[23]
      public 'customer_id' => string '10' (length=2)
      public 'cart' => string 'a:2:{s:32:"22d2d3d8584f6e0819c4e46af4d2fda2";a:9:{s:5:"rowid";s:32:"22d2d3d8584f6e0819c4e46af4d2fda2";s:2:"id";s:9:"101_94980";s:3:"qty";s:1:"1";s:5:"price";s:2:"64";s:4:"name";s:13:"Business Card";s:5:"image";s:18:"business-cards.gif";s:4:"ship";a:3:{s:6:"Ground";d:9.730000000000000426325641456060111522674560546875;s:11:"2nd Day Air";d:18.53999999999999914734871708787977695465087890625;s:9:"Overnight";d:26.269999999999999573674358543939888477325439453125;}s:7:"options";a:2:{s:17:"Print Description";s:164:"'... (length=1506)
      public 'shipping_type' => string 'Ground' (length=6)
      public 'shipping_cost' => string '19.46' (length=5)
      public 'order_sub_total' => string '148.25' (length=6)
      public 'order_total' => string '167.71' (length=6)
      public 'id' => string '29' (length=2)
      public 'timestamp' => string '2012-10-12 20:29:10' (length=19)
```

Notice `cart` is a multidimensional array. How do I loop through these objects and arrays and create a table?

```
<?php foreach($all_orders as $key => $val) : ?>

    <?php echo $key; ?>  <?php echo $val; ?>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

This causes the following error: *A PHP Error was encountered Severity: 4096 Message: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Access the properties of the `stdClass` object using the `->` operator:

```
<?php foreach($all_orders as $key => $val) : ?>
Customer ID <?php echo $val->customer_id ?> has a total of <?php echo $val->order_total ?><br />
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Comment: Hey that works great ... except how to echo out `cart`? Cart is a `serialized` array. `<?php echo unserialize($val->cart); ?>` It throws an error * Array to string conversion *

Comment: It looks like you would have to do something like: `$cart = unserialize($val->cart);  $key = array_keys($cart)[0]; // PHP 5.4+ echo $cart[$key]['price'];`

Comment: Reason being it appears the cart array is keyed by a hash code so you can't do `$cart[0]`

Comment: That's causing *Undefined offset: 0 error* and the following: ` $key = array_keys($cart)[0];` causes a SYNTAX error

Comment: Ok check this out if i do `echo $cart['f9bb1d342b1c2a0bfe982ef405369ec0']['price'];` I get the right output. So `$key` is not passing the right `index` So how do I get the correct index from the foreach loop? thanks for your help btw! :)

Comment: If each `$cart` array only has one index, use `$keys = array_keys($cart); $index = $keys[0];  $cart = $cart[$index];`

Comment: Hey, what do I do if a `cart` has more than 1 index? How would I do a `foreach` in this instance? I've exhausted all my ideas. Thanks for your help again!

Comment: Btw, If i do a `count($keys)` i appear to get the right value, but how do I pass the value to `$keys[*here*];`

Comment: hey I need your help. I think you're the only one who knows what I need to do. I even asked a new question regarding this ^.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12870253/how-to-pass-a-variable-in-a-foreach-to-get-all-the-indexes-of-an-array  -- If you have a moment please help me out.. Thank you ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
echo "<pre>";
foreach ( $cart as  $all_orders ) {
    foreach ( $all_orders as $key => $value ) {
        echo $key, " = ", $value, PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Comment: That kinda/sorta of works. I will play with this and get back to you. Thank you very much.

Comment: if you're still up please take a look at the comments between drew010 and I. Please advise if you know what I need to do. Thanks!

Comment: @fabio can see your answer is already selected ... need to go to bed now .. good day ..

Comment: yea just got it. Thank you for looking. Enjoy your evening. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

PHP 5 allows one to iterate over an object's *public* properties using a `foreach` loop.

For more information (and code examples): http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.iterations.php

Answer (score 0):

I use PHP's ArrayObject in my MVC:
us3.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayobject.php

```
        $arrayobject = new ArrayObject($dataRows);
        for ($iterator = $arrayobject->getIterator(); $iterator->valid(); $iterator->next()) {

        }
```