# How to pass a variable in a foreach .. to get all the indexes of an array

Tags: php, loops, foreach

Not sure if this is possible but here goes... i need to get all of the `indexes` of an array contained within an `object`

## foreach

```
<?php foreach($all_orders as $key => $val) : ?>

<?php 
    $cart = unserialize($val->cart);  
    $keys = array_keys($cart); 
    $x = count($keys); 
    $index = $keys[$x]; 
    $cart = $cart[$index]; 
?>

<?php $val->field_name; ?>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

## var_dump

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[22]
      public 'tracking_num' => string '1Z12345E1512345676' (length=18)
      public 'order_status' => string '1' (length=1)
      public 'cust_id' => string '10' (length=2)
      public 'cart' => string 'a:1:{s:32:"d9082c0e32bb353796d3bf8ebba34f71";a:9:{s:5:"rowid";s:32:"d9082c0e32bb353796d3bf8ebba34f71";s:2:"id";s:9:"101_44068";s:3:"qty";s:1:"1";s:5:"price";s:5:"104.5";s:4:"name";s:13:"Business Card";s:5:"image";s:18:"business-cards.gif";s:4:"ship";a:3:{s:6:"Ground";d:9.730000000000000426325641456060111522674560546875;s:11:"2nd Day Air";d:18.53999999999999914734871708787977695465087890625;s:9:"Overnight";d:26.269999999999999573674358543939888477325439453125;}s:7:"options";a:2:{s:17:"Print Description";s:16'... (length=784)
      public 'shipping_type' => string 'Overnight' (length=9)
      public 'shipping_cost' => string '26.27' (length=5)
      public 'order_sub_total' => string '104.50' (length=6)
      public 'order_total' => string '130.77' (length=6)
      public 'id' => string '30' (length=2)
      public 'timestamp' => string '2012-10-13 00:52:30' (length=19)
  1 => 
    object(stdClass)[23]
      public 'tracking_num' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'order_status' => string '0' (length=1)
      public 'cust_id' => string '10' (length=2)
      public 'cart' => string 'a:2:{s:32:"d7f14d223f7873bf93a3c0670b01609b";a:9:{s:5:"rowid";s:32:"d7f14d223f7873bf93a3c0670b01609b";s:2:"id";s:9:"101_96866";s:3:"qty";s:1:"1";s:5:"price";s:5:"84.25";s:4:"name";s:13:"Business Card";s:5:"image";s:18:"business-cards.gif";s:4:"ship";a:3:{s:6:"Ground";d:9.730000000000000426325641456060111522674560546875;s:11:"2nd Day Air";d:18.53999999999999914734871708787977695465087890625;s:9:"Overnight";d:26.269999999999999573674358543939888477325439453125;}s:7:"options";a:2:{s:17:"Print Description";s:16'... (length=1582)
      public 'shipping_type' => string 'Ground' (length=6)
      public 'shipping_cost' => string '37.62' (length=5)
      public 'order_sub_total' => string '622.25' (length=6)
      public 'order_total' => string '659.87' (length=6)
      public 'id' => string '31' (length=2)
      public 'timestamp' => string '2012-10-13 00:53:20' (length=19)
  2 => 
    object(stdClass)[24]
      public 'tracking_num' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'order_status' => string '0' (length=1)
      public 'cust_id' => string '10' (length=2)
      public 'cart' => string 'a:4:{s:32:"7670d6182aaad174954c5619079f48a1";a:9:{s:5:"rowid";s:32:"7670d6182aaad174954c5619079f48a1";s:2:"id";s:9:"101_32840";s:3:"qty";s:1:"1";s:5:"price";s:5:"84.25";s:4:"name";s:13:"Business Card";s:5:"image";s:18:"business-cards.gif";s:4:"ship";a:3:{s:6:"Ground";d:9.730000000000000426325641456060111522674560546875;s:11:"2nd Day Air";d:18.53999999999999914734871708787977695465087890625;s:9:"Overnight";d:26.269999999999999573674358543939888477325439453125;}s:7:"options";a:2:{s:17:"Print Description";s:16'... (length=3145)
      public 'shipping_type' => string 'Overnight' (length=9)
      public 'shipping_cost' => string '224.46' (length=6)
      public 'order_sub_total' => string '1,000.75' (length=8)
      public 'order_total' => string '1225.21' (length=7)
      public 'id' => string '32' (length=2)
      public 'timestamp' => string '2012-10-13 01:11:03' (length=19)
```

This code is contained inside of a `foreach` The var `$cart` contains an object of an `ARRAY` with multiple `indexes`. If I replace `$x` with `0` the loop will display the first index in the `cart` array. However some `cart` contain more than > 1 index.

`count($keys)` is properly echoing out the number of indexes in the `cart` array. For example I have 3 carts.

1. `cart` 1 has `1 index`
2. `cart` 2 has `2 index`
3. `cart` 3 has `4 index`

If i do `echo count($keys)` I get back `1 2 4`

How do I pass these values (in order) individually to my `$x` var for each loop?

**Notice how cart may have more than 1 index value**

Expect Output:

Each `cart`contains an array with multiple products. The foreach must iterate through and display each product in the array within `cart` Based on the var_dump shown above the expected output of the `cart` array should be in a table as follows:

```
<tr>0</tr> /*cart 1 has 1 index in the array*/
<tr>01</tr> /*cart 2 has 2 index in the array*/
<tr>0123</tr> /*cart 3 has 4 index in the array*/
```

Comment: please paste array structure of $cart and expected result array structure

Comment: @fabio - your question is very vogue. Please paste ALL your code and explain what you want to do inside the `foreach` loop. Also, post a `var_dump` of the `$cart` and the `$keys`

Comment: @fabio still your question and expected  output unclear. can you paste exact output ?

Comment: @GBD I made another edit in hopes to clarify any confusion. Thanks for the help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give try as below

You have each order can have multiple carts and each cart have multiple items.What you want to display # of items into each cart.

```
<?php 
    $cart = unserialize($val->cart);  
    $keys = array_keys($cart); // this will give you # of carts into one order
    //if now you want to count # of items into each cart then
    foreach($keys as $val){
      echo count($cart[$val]);
    }

?>
```

Comment: you want to merge all cart items into single array ?

Comment: what happen if you do $cart = $cart[$index]; foreach($cart as $value){echo $value['fieldname'];} or now paste whole code because it's now tuff to resolve this with small snippet

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question--and I'm not sure I do--you can use a simple `foreach` loop inside the loop that you don't show. (Or at least it's not in the question at the time that I'm writing this answer--maybe edit your question to show it, eh?)

This inner `foreach` loop would cycle through the values of `$keys` like this:

```
foreach ($keys as $this_key) {
    // whatever you want to do with the values of $keys here
    // each value will be available as $this_key
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Array indices start from 0 hence you should try:

```
$x = count($keys) -1
$index = $keys[$x]
```

All your indexes are saved in $keys and you can loop through it to get your respective elements like `$cart[$keys[0]], $cart[$keys[1]], ...`

This will give you the last array key of the array in `$index`.

Alternatively I would suggest you use the following to loop over all the keys of array $cart:

```
foreach($cart as $key=>$value){
   $cart[$key]; $value //Do whatever you want with the cart with the index $key or its value $value.
}
```

Comment: Hey yeah -- its not that simple, please look at my code -- question revised. thanks

Comment: Can you do a var dump of any of your `$cart` variables in the loop ?